# Simplify or reduce code size

Tags: c#, get, set, boolean

I have a problem with shorten the code in an application. I have this sample code and i want to make it smaller. The list contains other things like models,serials...etc. I only need to make more clean/readable. Ofc, the code is much much bigger than this:

```
public class SmartPhones
{
    public PhoneSettings()
    {
        Sony = true;
        Htc = true;
        Nokia = true;
        Iphone = true;

        SonyColor = Color Blue;
        HtcColor = Color Black;
        NokiaColor = Color Red;
        IphoneColor = Color White;
    }
    public ToggleButton Sony {get; set;}
    public ToggleButton Htc {get; set;}
    public ToggleButton Nokia {get; set;}
    public ToggleButton Iphone {get; set;}

    public ColorButton SonyColor {get; set;}
    public ColorButton HtcColor {get; set;}
    public ColorButton NokiaColor {get; set;}
    public ColorButton IphoneColor {get; set;}
}
```

Thank you all for any small help!

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. Not only do you have multiple properties with the same names, but you are assigning Boolean and colour values to these even though they are defined as `ToggleButton` and `ColorButton`. Please post some complete, working code.

Comment: @Bassie is right, and the only way I can think of is to shorten `Sony = true;
        Htc = true;
        Nokia = true;
        Iphone = true;` to `Sony = Htc = Nokia = Iphone = true;`

Comment: @Bassie The code is working as it is. Sony(toggle-ON/OFF, ColorButton) than the functions(get-set) for both (true/false-colors). But the code is really huge.

Comment: In that case it will be difficult to help, as I can't see how this code works at all, let alone what can be done to reduce it. Based on what I can see however, I would agree with @manda in that it should probably be restructured.

Comment: The code you´ve posted does *not* work, not even compile. So as long as you don´t provide a working example of the code that shows what you actually *do* it´s quite hard to guess what you *want* it to be.

Comment: I have fixed the code sample....Sorry for misguiding, :(...And ToggleButton-ColorButton are functions.

Comment: ToggleButton,ColorButton are Class type.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what you wanted to achieve, but to me, it seems more logical to create Phone class with all properties, and then to create SmartPhones class containing all the instances of Phone with proper attributes. 
Something like this

```
    public class Phone
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string ToggleButton { get; set; }
        public string ColorButton { get; set; }
    }

    public class SmartPhones
    {
        private List<Phone> _list = new List<Phone>();

        public SmartPhones()
        {
            _list.Add(new Phone { Type = "Htc", ToggleButton = "aa", ColorButton = "bb"});
            _list.Add(new Phone { Type = "Nokia", ToggleButton = "aa", ColorButton = "bb" });
            _list.Add(new Phone { Type = "Sony", ToggleButton = "aa", ColorButton = "bb" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize the `_list` :)